# Magento 2 : How to get order id for a guest customer in controller after click on place order button?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I have created payment method module. In this module when i was logged in, it was successfully got order id from **Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface** interface. but when i was guest, i was not able to get order id from **Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface** interface.
I was search in google and found that, for guest customer interface was changed **Magento\Quote\Api\GuestCartManagementInterface**. I have also try this interface, but still not working for get order id of guest customer.
When i have click on place order button, My module controller is called.
My controller code is given below.

```
<?php 

namespace Mageniks\Testpayment\Controller\Payment; 


use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\GuestCartManagementInterface;

class Redirect extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action 
{
    /**
     * Customer session model
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_customerSession;
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $_paymentMethod;
    protected $_checkoutSession;
    protected $checkout;
    protected $cartManagement;
    protected $guestcartManagement;
    protected $orderRepository;
    protected $_scopeConfig;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Mageniks\Testpayment\Model\PaymentMethod $paymentMethod,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        CartManagementInterface $cartManagement,
        GuestCartManagementInterface $guestcartManagement

    ) {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_paymentMethod = $paymentMethod;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->cartManagement = $cartManagement;
        $this->guestcartManagement = $guestcartManagement;
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;


    }

    public function execute()
    {

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
        $orderId = '';
        if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) 
        {
            // FOR LOGIN CUSTOMER GET ORDER ID

              $orderId = $this->cartManagement->placeOrder($this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getId());
        }
        else
        {
                  // FOR GUEST CUSTOMER GET ORDER ID

                   try 
                   {
                      $orderId = $this->guestcartManagement->placeOrder($this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getId());

                    } catch (\Exception $e) 
                    {
                        echo $e->getMessage();
                    }

         }

        $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
        if ($order){
            $order->setState($this->_scopeConfig->getValue('payment/testpayment/new_order_status', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE));
            $order->setStatus($this->_scopeConfig->getValue('payment/testpayment/new_order_status', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE));
            $order->save();
        }

    }

}

?>
```

How can I get order id for guest customer in controller after click on place order button ? Please help me. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: on success page magento automatically show order id for guest user too. Or you can use session for get order id.
`Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();`

Comment: I am using magento 2. I was also try to fetch order id from checkout session, but it will return blank : $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrderId();

Comment: My controller called before success page, so i am not able to got order object

Answer (score 0):

Is the order correctly registered for guest customers ? Do you have any exceptions ?

Maybe you can try this :

```
$quote->setCustomerId(null)
        ->setCustomerEmail($quote->getBillingAddress()->getEmail())
        ->setCustomerIsGuest(true)
        ->setCustomerGroupId(Group::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID);
$quote->collectTotals();
$orderId = $this->cartManagement->placeOrder($quote->getId());
```

I never tested my code without it though, but no matter the type of customer I always have my order id.